# What is the output of the code?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%x",-2<<2);  //left shift of a negative integer
    return 0;
}
```

If negative integers are represented with a sign bit, then I fear the sign bit will be lost.
Please explain a bit.

Comment: The best approach here is for you to compile and run the code. Then ask specific questions about something that is confusing you.

Comment: The C99 standard says that this is undefined behavior, and therefore no explanation is likely to be useful.  Don't do it.  If you try it, you'll get an answer good for the current version of your compiler on your current system, and there's no actual guarantee it will happen the same way on your system in different circumstances.  See the C99 standard, 6.5.7/4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is at best 'implementation defined', and possibly 'undefined behaviour'.

Comment: C99 draft standard, 6.5.7/4.  Undefined behavior.

Comment: This is what at read at many places.But somewhere it is explained that negative integers are stored as 2's complement.And applying the left shift normally on 2's complement will give the desrired result.What about this?

Comment: @Abhishek kumar: 'undefined behaviour' means it may produce the answer you expect but it's not guaranteed. You can't rely on it because it's allowed to produce a different effect with a different compiler, compiler settings, architecture, operating system, etc. If you are lucky it will crash quickly in testing. If you aren't lucky it will wait to fail until your most important client uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Negative integers don't have a "sign bit". `-2` is stored as `0xFFFFFFFE`.

Also, `<<` doesn't do what you think. In C, it is an arithmetical (rather than a logical) shift. So `x << y` is basically `x * 2 ^ y` for positive `x`, where `^` denotes exponentiation.

Lastly, you should **never** use shift operations for signed integers. It might generate unexpected results in a certain number of cases (negative `x` is one of them) and it's not worth to rule all of them out.

If you want to multiply `-2` by `4`, just do it...

Comment: << is an arithmetical shift in case of both signed and unsigned?

Comment: Both for signed and unsigned integers, but `<<` is simply undefined for negative `x`. Your compiler will try to make sense of it (and, possibly, even do what you want), but you can't rely on that. Even a never version of the same compiler (or an optimization switch), could alter the results of the operation.